# Why is this axiom written twice?

Tags: logic, axioms

There are three axiom in this axiomatic system $A_1$:
1. $\alpha \rightarrow (\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$
2. $(\alpha \rightarrow (\beta \rightarrow \gamma)) \rightarrow ((\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \gamma))$
3. $(\neg \beta \rightarrow \neg \alpha) \rightarrow ((\neg \beta \rightarrow \alpha) \rightarrow \beta)$

Using *Modus Ponens* we can prove that $(\neg P \rightarrow P) \rightarrow P$ is a theorem of this axiomatic system:
1. $\neg P \rightarrow [(\neg P \rightarrow \neg P) \rightarrow \neg P]|A1$
2. $\{\neg P \rightarrow [(\neg P \rightarrow \neg P) \rightarrow \neg P]\} \rightarrow \{[\neg P \rightarrow (\neg P \rightarrow \neg P)] \rightarrow (\neg P \rightarrow \neg P)\}|A2$
3. $[\neg P \rightarrow (\neg P \rightarrow \neg P)] \rightarrow (\neg P \rightarrow \neg P)|1,2MP$
4. $\neg P \rightarrow (\neg P \rightarrow \neg P)|A1$
5. $\neg P \rightarrow \neg P|3,4MP$
6. $(\neg P \rightarrow \neg P) \rightarrow [(\neg P \rightarrow P) \rightarrow P]|A3$
7. $(\neg P \rightarrow P) \rightarrow P|5,6MP$

What I don't understand is why the first axiom ($A1$) is written twice (steps 1 and 4). The first step suggests these values for variables $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$: $\alpha = \neg P, \beta = \neg P \rightarrow \neg P, \gamma = \neg P$, but the fourth one these: $\alpha = \neg P, \beta = \neg P, \gamma = \neg P$.

Comment: You shouldn't think of $A1$ as a single axiom, but rather as a schema, infinitely many axioms, all of them of the same form (but with $\alpha,\beta$ ranging over all possible propositional formulas). The proof you are looking at uses two axioms of the form $A1$. That's fine, just as you used $MP$ several times, although in each instance applied to different groups of formulas. Why would this be a problem?

Comment: @Vuk As you yourself noticed, the claim on line 1 is a different claim from the one on line 4, even as both are instances of $A1$. And since the proof needs both claims, you need to use the axiom twice; once for each claim.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought that once you define the values of variables, you can't change them later in proof. But when I think about it, you actually can. If axioms are schemes that will always yield a logical truth, then no matter which values you take (even if you use same axiom with different values in same proof) you will get tautology. And by rules of inference (which are truth perserving) you will definitely get tautologies from axioms. Do I get it now?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: There is a method of storing proofs (like computer science data type) that records them as a typed lambda expression.  When doing do, a theorem that is used twice has to be recorded twice (usually).  The repetition of 1 and 4 is probably an indirect consequence of that idiosyncrasy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axioms are only schemes in which you plug in wffs for variables, you can use one axiom as a scheme multiple times in a proof, pluging in different wffs for different instances of axiom.

Any axiomatic system is composed out of two types of wffs: axiomatic and wffs derived from axiomic wffs using rules of inference (since axioms are by default logical truths, wffs created from must be logical truths too, for only logical truths are allowed to be in axiomatic proof, and anything that is derived from any wff using rules of inference is logical truth, because rules of inference are truth perserving).

Since axioms are logical truths, you can use their instances more than once in a proof with different wffs, because any of those wffs created from axioms is logical truth, even if you use different values in different instances of axiom.

Sometimes you need more than one instance of axiom to prove a theorem in that axiomatic system (theorem being nothing more than wff in a proof that is not axiomatic and not assumption, i.e. wff that is derived from axiomatic wffs using rules of inference).